# what guarantees that $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

$f:X\to Y$ be a continuous injective map, $Y$ be a Hausdorff , We need to prove  $X$ is Hausdorff too.

$a,b\in X$ such that $a\ne b$ so $f(a)\ne f(b)$, so $\exists V_1,V_2$ open sets containing $f(a),f(b)$ and $V_1\cap V_2=\emptyset$. Due to continuity $a\in U_1=f^{-1}(V_1),b\in U_2=f^{-1}(V_2)$ where $U_1,U_2$ are open in $X$, Now my question is what guarantees that $U_1\cap U_2=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 6):

Note that $U_1 \cap U_2 = f^{-1} [ V_1 ] \cap f^{-1} [ V_2 ] = f^{-1} [ V_1 \cap V_2 ] = f^{-1} [ \varnothing ]$.

---

Essentially, it is because the inverse image operation respects the basic set-theoretic operations:  If $f : X \to Y$, then

- $f^{-1} [ B_1 ] \cup f^{-1} [ B_2 ] = f^{-1} [ B_1 \cup B_2 ]$;
- $f^{-1} [ B_1 ] \cap f^{-1} [ B_2 ] = f^{-1} [ B_1 \cap B_2 ]$;
- $f^{-1} [ Y \setminus B ] = X \setminus f^{-1} [ B ]$.

This is in dramatic difference to the "forward image" operation, which only respects the union operation in general.